# Recorrer, comparar y asignar diccionarios y listas

Tags: python, array, lista

Tengo un array llamado `labels` tal que asi:

```
labels
Out[15]: array([ 0,  1,  2, ...,  7, 10, -1])
```

Tengo tambien un diccionario llamado `IDnodes` el cual contiene por cada key un array de tipo booleano y cada array es de una longitud diferente.

Quiero tener un diccionario llamado `Temp` en el que almacenar por cada key (del mismo valor que en IDnodes) una lista como la de `labels` pero que cumpla lo siguiente, por ejemplo:

```
IDnodes[key1]=array([ True, False, False, ..., False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Si el valor de un determinado key es True, entonces quiero guardar en `Temp` de esa misma key el valor de `labels` de esa misma posicion.

`labels` se recorrer desde el primer valor y solo se avanza posicion si  el valor de IDnodes es True, si es False no se avanza.

Si el valor es False, entonces quiero guardar un valor de `-1`.

Y entonces tener en`Temp[key1]` algo como:

```
Temp[key1]=array([ 5, -1, -1, ..., -1, -1,  8], dtype=int64)
```

Mis intentos han sido en vano:

```
i=0
lista=[]
Temp=dict.fromkeys(IDnodes.keys(),[])
for mmsi, val in IDnodes.items():
    for p in val:
        if p:
            lista.append(labels[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            lista.append(-1)
    Temp[mmsi]=lista
    lista=[]
```

Comment: Juanca la pregunta llega a ser bastante confusa o al menos para mi (puede que esté espeso hoy...XD), ¿podrias poner un ejemplo real con la salida esperada para ese ejemplo? Es decir, agrega un `labels` y un `IDnodes` pequeños y para ellos la salida que esperarias. Por otro lado los 'arrays' son arrays de NumPy verdad?. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una línea de código, mira.

```
i = 0
lista=[]
Temp=dict.fromkeys(IDnodes.keys(),[])
for mmsi, val in IDnodes.items():
    for p in val:
        if p:
            lista.append(labels[mmsi][i]) # <- aquí
            i+=1
        else:
            lista.append(-1)
    Temp[mmsi]=lista
    lista=[]
```

Alternativa 1:

```
Temp=dict.fromkeys(IDnodes.keys(),[])
for mmsi, val in IDnodes.items():
    lista=[]
    for i, p in enumerate(val):
        if p:
            lista.append(labels[mmsi][i])
        else:
            lista.append(-1)
    Temp[mmsi]=lista
```

Alternativa 2

```
Temp = {}
for mmsi, val in IDnodes.items():
    Temp[mmsi] = [(labels[mmsi][i] if p else -1) \
                  for i, p in enumerate(val)
                  ]
```